# AngularJS - how do I make controller register every change of window's global variable in simple way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular only as module to show content of array in unordered list.

My code is as follows:

```
// script.js - plain JS:
let array = []

element.addEventListener('click',function append(){
     array.push(someValue);
})


// ng-app and ng-controller are set only on UL element, 
// click listener is set on other element outside of ng-app's / controller's scope, array is window's global variable 
// in angular app.js controller - this doesn't work:
$scope.$watch(()=>return $window.array.length,
              (oldVal, newVal)=>{ 
                console.log(oldVal, newVal );
                $scope.array = $window.array
              })
```

$watch doesn't do anything when mouse click updates array, it only does what it should when window loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working, because `$scope.$watch` associated with `$digest` cycle, so you should mannually start it with the help of events mechanism: `$rootScope.$broadcast` and `$scope.$on`(instead of `$scope.$watch`):

```js
let array = []

function register($rootScope, element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function append() {
    array.push(array.length + 1);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('customEvent', array.length);
  })
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    register($rootScope, document.getElementById('test'));
  })
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.logs = [];
    $scope.$on('customEvent', function(event, data) {      
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.logs.push(data);
      });
    })
  })
```

```css
h4{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <h4 id='test'>Click ME</h4>
  <ul ng-if='logs.length > 0'>
    <li ng-repeat='log in logs'>{{log}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```